# Invalid Syntax (case "$1" in)

Tags: raspberry-pi, case, sh, init

I'm programming my Raspberry Pi B+ and editing a !/bin/sh file but keep getting a syntax error in Python 2 in the second " of the "case "$1" in".

My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        envmon
# Required-Start:  $local_fs
# Required-Stop:   $local_fs
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:    0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/stop envmon
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    /home/pi/tempsense/opt/envmon/dht11 &
    echo "Starting envmon"
    /home/pi/tempsense/opt/envmon/displayenvmon.py &
    ;;
  stop)
    pkill dht11
    pkill displayenvmon
    echo "envmon stopped"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /home/pi/tempsense/etc/init.d/envmon {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I'm a beginner to python. Any help or advised is appreciated.

Comment: How is python relevant?  This is a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is a shell script, not a Python script.

To run the script, you have the following options:

1. Mark the script as executable

   ```
   chmod +x /path/to/script
   /path/to/script
   ```
2. Call the command interpreter `sh`

   ```
   sh /path/to/script
   ```

Comment: You should note that this is easily detectable if you read the shebang: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies and help - sorry for any confusion.
Do you happen to know how I could run this script from start-up?

Comment: @WullbertDuncan You may take a look [here](http://superuser.com/q/685471/405086).

Comment: @WullbertDuncan You can mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark on the left of the answer.